# CAMetalLayer.nextDrawable takes much time, even more than 8ms

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

CAMetalLayer.nextDrawable() should not be a very time-comsuming method.But sometimes it often takes much time, even more than 8ms

1. Copy the code below
2. Follow the comment guide in `viewDidLoad`
3. See the log print

```swift
class TestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let metalLayer:CAMetalLayer = CAMetalLayer()
    
    var displayLink:CADisplayLink!
    
    var thread:Thread!
    
    var animationView:AnimationView!
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.displayLink.isPaused = true
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.displayLink.isPaused = false
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print("ahhhaa")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        metalLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        metalLayer.drawableSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * scale, height: self.view.frame.height * scale)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(metalLayer)
        self.addDisplayLinkInUITaskRunner()
        
        // Wait screen loading complete,and next,You can:
        
        // 1. Swipe down the control center, you will see a lot log print in console, and it will
        //                      constantly exists.
        
        // 2. Move the app to bg, and then move to fg, you will see a lot of log,
        //      it also will constantly exist for a long time.
        
        // 3. Just don't do anything, you might see it the log print constantly....
        //      And when you tap the screen, it may disappear, and After a while, you may see log again....
    }
    
    func addDisplayLinkInUITaskRunner() {
        self.thread = Thread(block: {
            RunLoop.current.add(NSMachPort(), forMode: .common)
            RunLoop.current.run()
        })
        self.thread.name = ""
        self.thread.start()
        
        self.perform(#selector(addDisplayLink), on: thread, with: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
    }
    
    @objc func addDisplayLink() {
        self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(onDisplayLink))
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            self.displayLink.preferredFrameRateRange = .init(minimum: 60, maximum: 120, preferred: 120)
        } else {
            self.displayLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 120
        }
        self.displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    @objc private func onDisplayLink() {
        let startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let frameDrawable = metalLayer.nextDrawable()!
        let timeUsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime
        
        // If time used to get next drawble over 3ms,
        // we print it here to indicate this method take much time!
        if (timeUsed > 0.005) {
            print("CAMetalLayer.nextDrawable take much time!! -> \(String(format: "%.2f", timeUsed * 1000)) ms")
        }
        frameDrawable.present()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sanity check: is this a release build? Did try commenting out all your debug `print`s?

Comment: @Kamil.S Yes. Release build. I have commenting out all my debugprint and only leave`print("CAMetalLayer.nextDrawable take much time!! -> \(String(format: "%.2f", timeUsed * 1000)) ms")`

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`displaySyncEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cametallayer/2887087-displaysyncenabled) set to `true` (the default) it will wait for the next vsync to display the drawable. This means you can very quickly run out of drawables, and so `nextDrawable` will wait until one becomes available (or up to 1 second).

In other words, since you already have drawables queued to be presented, you can't get another one until one actually becomes available.

If you indeed want to present them as fast as possible - set `displaySyncEabled` to `false`. However, the current behavior may just be what you want, since you rarely gain anything from displaying frames faster than the display's refresh rate.

Comment: Thx for your answer , but I m on iOS instead of macos, so displaySyncEabled cannot be used....

Comment: Then it would appear you cannot go around this, as the layer won't display drawables any faster regardless.